# How to give an dynamicly loaded TreeViewItem an EventHandler?

Tags: dynamic, javafx, treeview, mouseevent

at the moment i programm a database based Chat System.
The friendlist of every User gets loadet in a TreeView after the login.

means:
After the login I request the names of the useres friends by the following Funktion, 
`String namesSt[] = get.getUserFriendNameByUserID(currentUserID);`

To use the given Names to load them as TreeItem into my Friendlist / TreeRootItem "rootItem"

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < namesSt.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println(namesSt[counter]);
        TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> (namesSt[counter]);

        item.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,handler);

        rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
    }
```

When I now add my rootItem, I see the Names in the TreeView.
But if I click on a name, the given MouseEventHandler doesn´t get called.

Further I just want to request the text of the Element which trigger the MouseEvent, so that i can submit these name to a spezial funktion.

How can i realice such an MouseEvent? 
How is it possible to call it from the dynamicly created TreeItem?

Thank you for any help :)

cheerse
Tobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeItem`s represent the data, not the UI component. So they don't generate mouse events. You need to register the mouse listener on the `TreeCell`. To do this, set a cell factory on the `TreeView`. The cell factory is a function that creates `TreeCell`s as they are needed. Thus this will work for dynamically added tree items too.

You will need something like this:

```
TreeView<String> treeView ;

// ...

treeView.setCellFactory( tv -> {
    TreeCell<String> cell = new TreeCell<>();
    cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
    cell.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
            String value = cell.getItem();
            TreeItem<String> treeItem = cell.getTreeItem(); // if needed
            // process ...
        }
    });
    return cell ;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand this example at all. How would this example work if the TreeCell is not of String but of CustomObject? Especially `cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());` I do not understand: Where should the just created TreeCell objet have any itemProperty got from?

Comment: If it's not a `String`, then you either use a different binding, or a listener on the `itemProperty` that updates the text property, or use a `TreeCell` implementation that overrides `updateItem(...)`. Read the [`Cell` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) for a full explanation of how cells work.

Comment: I tried it that way: http://pastebin.com/UDv1ziZQ Result is, that there is 0,1,2,3 displayed and after that everything is NULL. I just do not get the concept ...