# Access treeItem, not treeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I would like to access the treeItems in my treeView via mouse clicked. I have no problem to access the treeview because I can call treeView.setOnMouseClicked, but the treeItem doesn't have that method. I have tried a few things like tried EventHandler, but can't get it to work:

```
    TreeItem<String> soc1Root = new TreeItem<String>("Bla - 1");
    soc1Root.setExpanded(true);

    TreeItem<String> soc1 = new TreeItem<String>("UnderBla - 1");
    soc1.setExpanded(true);
    soc1Root.getChildren().add(soc1);

    TreeItem<String> termisk = new TreeItem<String>("Stuff happen when clicked!");
    soc1.getChildren().add(termisk);

    socialKval = new TreeView<String>(soc1Root);

    pane.setLeft(socialKval);

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandle = (MouseEvent event) -> {
            getTermisk(pane);
            System.out.println("Termisk - test");
        };

        termisk.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEventHandle);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give an dynamicly loaded TreeViewItem an EventHandler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301086/how-to-give-an-dynamicly-loaded-treeviewitem-an-eventhandler)

Comment: "How to give an dynamicly loaded TreeViewItem an EventHandler?" - gave me the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply listen to the selection model's selected item:

```
treeview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

OR

```
treeview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();
```

Happy Coding,
Kalasch